# How do built-in functions work in Javascript or NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I come from the java world. As far as I remember there are no built in functions in java which you can use out of the box in your source code.

So I was surprised how it works in javascript. I saw in Node.js  that I could use require() without having to import anything. How does that work. What would happen if I also define a require method somewhere else.  I think that would cause problems. How do I import methods anyway in javascript. I remember when there was also html then you could use script tag.

Comment: It's not cut and dry. ES6 defines require, but earlier and browser implementations need a shim like require.js to mimic packages. Javascript doesn't really have packages on its own. Someone else can probably expand on this but look at require.js and the es5 vs es6 ways of doing it

Answer (score 0):

require is a function argument because each module in node.js is wrapped as

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// Module code actually lives in here
});
```

if you in any way redefine `require` - you will use the redefined version

Comment: i do no understand this sorry.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper